# Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac and error ';' expected

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a slider in Android Studio and encountered 2 errors in my code. Here is the first one.

Here is the error:

```
'error: ';' expected
```

This is the line in which the error occured

```
If (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

And the second error is this, but I don't have any idea where to look for this error since I'm just new to java and this is the first time I encountered this.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

This is my complete code.

```
package mac.mac.dictionary;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Viewpager viewpager;
private Intromanager intromanager;
private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
private TextView[] dots;
Button next,skip;
private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private int[] layouts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    intromanager = new Intromanager(this);
    if(!intromanager.Check())
    {
        intromanager.setFirst(false);
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)
    {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutDots);
    skip=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    layouts = new int[]{R.layout.activity_screen_1,R.layout.activity_screen_2,R.layout.activity_screen_3};
    addBottomDots(0);
    changeStatusBarColor();
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListener);


    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)  {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if(current<layouts.length)
            {
                viewpager.setCurrentItem(current);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void addBottomDots(int position)
{

    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];
    int[] colorActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.dot_active);
    int[] colorInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.dot_inactive);
    dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for(int i=0; i<dots.length; i++)
    {
        dots[i]=new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorInactive[position]);
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }
    if(dots.length>0)
        dots[position].setTextColor(colorActive[position]);
}


private int getItem(int i)
{
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
}
Viewpager.OnPageChangeListener viewListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        addBottomDots(position);
        if(position==layouts.length-1)
        {
            next.setText("PROCEED");
            skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else

        {
            next.setText("NEXT");
            skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};

private void changeStatusBarColor()
{
    If (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position],container,false);
        container.addView(v);
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View v =(View)object;
        container.removeView(v);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `If (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)=` is not syntactically valid at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
```

try this

Comment: Should probably be `>=`